# Is there a way to trim all the values read using PropertyPlaceholder

Tags: java, spring

I am using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load a property file in my application from that I reading the database details and replacing it dynamically in  data source as shown below.

```
<bean id="configJdbcProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:config.properties
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mysqlSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${mysql.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${mysql.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mysql.jdbc.password}" /> </bean>
```

The above code works fine as expected.
Problem:
If there is any space in the above said properties value will leads to application failure.

```
Ex: mysql.jdbc.username= root
```

Now in the above example there is a space before user name root because of which my application fails to connect to DB.
I accept it is a human error but is there a way in spring to handle it automatically or by enabling some properties in spring.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support in the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for trimming values because it assumes your property source is correct. Still, it's simple to introduce. There is nothing stopping you from using a custom version of the class.

```
public class MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder, Properties props) {
        String value = super.resolvePlaceholder(placeholder, props);
        return value == null ? null : value.trim();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually I am not aware of such an Mechanism. But this seems to be a duplicate of [Automatically Trim Trailing White Space for properties in Props file loaded into Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031905/automatically-trim-trailing-white-space-for-properties-in-props-file-loaded-into)

Also there is an Issue which is still in status "Unresolved" in Spring Jira.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5839

Hope I could help you.

BR