# Automatically trim trailing white space for properties in properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

Spring doesn't trim the values given in properties file. As per the discussion here, it looks like they have kept in intentionally.
However, in our project, we want to trim the values automatically before it is getting used in the application.

I am using 2.1.4.RELEASE.

I tried by adding following Bean configuration

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]{new ClassPathResource("application.properties")};
    ppc.setLocations(resources);
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    ppc.setTrimValues(true);
    return ppc;
}
```

Because of this setting, it is not able to load properties file and throwing following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'kafka.groupId' in value "${kafka.groupId}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
```

Anyone has tried to solve this problem?

I referred the following links but didn't get much help.

[Automatically Trim Trailing White Space for properties in Props file loaded into Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031905/automatically-trim-trailing-white-space-for-properties-in-props-file-loaded-into),

https://htr3n.github.io/2018/11/spring-boot-trailing-whitespaces/

Comment: what's your spring boot version?

Comment: @clevertension 2.1.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it would be to "hack" the spEl Expression to force the use of the String.trim() function.

Let's say you have a property `test.myvalue` equal to `azerty`   (with trailing spaces) in the `application.properties` file, then you could inject this property in your class like this :

```
@Value("#{'${test.myvalue}'.trim()}")
String myvalue;
```

The resulting `myvalue` will be equal to `azerty` (no trailing spaces) once injected in your class.

Obviously this trimming won't be set globally to all injected values in your app, and you'll have to do it to all injected value, but I think this approach gives more flexibility.